# What is the difference between dataview and datatable?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

What is the difference between DataView and DataTable in .NET?
As far as I understand, DataView is just a false presentation of DataTable.
When should I use DataView?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

When you want to run a query and show the subset of data in a control, a DataView could help you. That's just one example, look at the [MSDN example for DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), that explains where you should use DataViews with DataTables...

**DataTable**

A datatable is an in-memory representation of a single database table. You can think of it as having columns and rows in the same way. The DataTable is a central object in the ADO.NET library. Other objects that use the DataTable include the DataSet and the DataView.

Look at MSDN The [DataTable class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more details.

**DataView**

A dataview is a view on a datatable, a bit like a sql view. It allows you to filter and sort the rows - often for binding to a windows form control.

Additionally, a DataView can be customized to present a subset of data from the DataTable. This capability allows you to have two controls bound to the same DataTable, but showing different versions of the data. For example, one control may be bound to a DataView showing all of the rows in the table, while a second may be configured to display only the rows that have been deleted from the DataTable. The DataTable also has a DefaultView property which returns the default DataView for the table.

Look at MSDN [DataView class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 14):

The `Datatable` is the unordered and unfiltered collection of DataRows extracted according to your query from your database.
The DataView (and you could have more than one) is a filtered and/or ordered view of the same data.

For example:

```
 using(SqlConnection cn = GetConnection())
 {
     cn.Open();
     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Customers", cn);
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     da.Fill(dt);

     // At this point dt is filled with datarows extracted from the database in no particular order 
     // And the DefaultView presents the same record organization (or lack of), but...

     // Order on the default view by CustomerName
     dt.DefaultView.Sort = "CustomerName";
     foreach(DataRowView rv in dt.DefaultView)
          Console.WriteLine(rv["CustomerName"].ToString();

     // A new dataview with only a certain kind of customers ordered by name
     DataView dvSelectedCust = new DataView(dt, "CreditLevel = 1", "CustomerName", DataViewRowState.Unchanged);
     foreach(DataRowView rv in dvSelectedCust)
          Console.WriteLine(rv["CustomerName"],ToString();



 }
```

Of course creating and maintaining a DataView is an hit on performances and thus you have the choice to use it only when you really need it

Answer (score 8):

`DataTable` means single table representation whereas a `DataSet` is a multiple table representation.

That means by using `DataTable` we can hold only one single table from the database, if we use `DataSet` we can hold multiple tables at a time...

`DataView` means view of data available in `DataSet`...(view of table available in `DataSet`)
it is used to find a record, sort, filter the record... by using `DataView`.

Answer (score 6):

you can have filtering on DataTable with DataView. for example if you have a DataSet that include all parameters you can find one of the parameters with DataView :

```
DataView dv = new DataView();
dv = new DataView(parameterDs.Tables[0], "ParameterName = '@" + parameter.Key + "'", string.Empty, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are lot of links available of internet related to this but for summary

> DataView is customized view of a DataTable for sorting, filtering, searching, editing, and navigation. The DataView does not store data, but instead represents a connected view of its corresponding DataTable.

You can look into simple DataView [Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.data.dataview.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) in VB.

Answer (score 1):

DataView is additional layer that is used to filter or apply expresssion sorting etc..

DataView contains operators such as `RowFilter`

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.dataview.aspx