# Cloning of Data View with empty Table

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, dataview

I have Data View source and this need to be cloned to new Data View. So that i can apply my own filter with affecting the original source.

I have tried to get this with that `Table.Clone()` or `Table.Copy()`, but it doesn't works for me since its table is empty. So how to clone a Data view without its table?

Any idea on this?

[image]

Comment: You don't.  There is no DataView without a table.  See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382932/what-is-the-difference-between-dataview-and-datatable

Comment: @DonBoitnott: above i have inserted the image of empty table. wherer source is DataView. But in this empty table, it has the collection of column and its value. is this empty is just shown for view?

Answer (score 1):

Here are three possible ways :

```
datatable = DataView.ToTable()


datatable = DataViev.Table.Copy(),


datatable = DataView.Table.Clone();
```

Comment: DataView's Table is empty. if it is copied or cloned, empty DataView returned. How could i return the DataView alone?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. Could you please explain a little further. You should consider that DataViews always depend on a table.