# Correct way to determine DataGridView DataSource is DataTable or DataView in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

What is the correct way to determine **DataGridView** **DataSource** is **DataTable** or **DataView** in order to this code snippet.

```
//data bind
myDataTable = getDataTableFromDataBase()
datagridview1.DataSource = myDataTable;
```

Then I try to get DataTable from above DataGridView I did this.

```
DataTable temp = (DataTable)(this.datagridview1.DataSource);
```

Then it's gave me an error like this, **Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataView' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'**

when I want to get data source from DataGridView I do this nasty thing.
**This is work but what is the best way?**

```
 DataTable dt_update = new DataTable();
                try
                    {
                        DataView dv = (DataView)(this.datagridview1.DataSource);
                        tempTable = (DataTable)dv.Table;                            
                    }
                    catch (InvalidCastException ex)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                           tempTable = (DataTable)datagridview1.DataSource;
                        }
                        catch { }
                    }
```

Comment: Maybe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382932/what-is-the-difference-between-dataview-and-datatable could help you clarify

Comment: Btw, why do you have three tables `dt_update`, `dtbl` and `tempTable`? At least one seems to be redundant. What do you want to do with the table?

Answer (score 3):

Try like this

```
if(datagridview1.DataSource is DataTable)
{
    dt_update = (DataTable)datagridview1.DataSource
}
else if (datagridview1.DataSource is DataView)
{
    dt_update = (DataView)datagridview1.DataSource.Table
}
```

Comment: It's help me to find `is` keyword usage

Comment: @Jimmer you can also do it like this: datagridview1.DataSource.GetType() == typeof(DataTable)

Answer (score 2):

One way, use the [`as` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) to try-cast it:

```
DataTable dtbl = datagridview1.DataSource as DataTable;
if(dtbl == null)
    dtbl = (datagridview1.DataSource as DataView).Table; 
tempTable = dtbl;
```

Comment: It's help me to find `as` keyword usage

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
           try
           {
               DataTable dt_update = datagridview1.DataSource.GetType() == typeof(DataView) ? ((DataView)datagridview1.DataSource).Table : (DataTable)datagridview1.DataSource;
           }
           catch (Exception)
           {

               throw;
           }
```