# New DataView vs. DefaultView of a DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, dataview

Why would you construct a new `DataView` instead of using the `DefaultView` of the `DataTable` in C#?

What are the scenarios creating a new `DataView` is preferable?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of both?

`var dataView = new DataView(dataTable);`

vs

`var dataView = dataTable.DefaultView;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [DefaultView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has the advantage of being there already by default, as the name implies.

Additional [DataViews](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.dataview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) have the advantage of allowing you to keep several of them ready and in use **in parallel**.

So you can **filter** and **sort** 3 of them in different ways and bind 3 different controls, e.g. `three DataGridViews`  or a `DGV` and the `Items` of a `ComboboxCell` to them **independently**.

Quoting from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382932/what-is-the-difference-between-dataview-and-datatable):

> A dataview is a view on a datatable, a bit like a sql view. It allows
>   you to filter and sort the rows - often for binding to a windows form
>   control. Additionally, a DataView can be customized to present a
>   subset of data from the DataTable. This capability allows you to have
>   two controls bound to the same DataTable, but showing different
>   versions of the data.

Answer (score 0):

And another scenarios creating a new DataView is preferable, it is asp global (app variable) datatable shared between sessions. Defaultview with rowfilter not preferable, because  applied filter affect all sessions defaultview. So you must create dataview for every session.
vb.net

```
Application("dt") = New DataTable() - persits across sessions
Application("dt").DefaultView.RowFilter="Field = Value" - not preferable because it apply all sessions
Session("dv") = New DataView(Application("dt"))
Session("dv").RowFilter="Field = Value" - preferable
```

Comment: Maxrem, this does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Disagree . It is scenarios creating a new DataView is preferable, which asked.

Comment: In that case please take my apology and rephrase your answer, so that it reads less like "I have the same problem, it does not work, what I need is ...". For an answer the most misleading phrases are "I use", "not good", "I need" and the final inconsequentially trailing off "...".

Comment: Edit / rephrase my answer.

Comment: I see. Yes, now is reads much more like an answer. Thank you for taking my ciriticism in such a matter-of-fact way.